# How to save all firebase notifications to firebase realtime database when notification is received

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Am trying to save all notification message to Firebase Realtime Database. But it doesn't work when app is not running, any notification that is received when app is closed will not be saved to Firebase Database. But any notification that is received when am making use of the app will be saved.

Please can anyone advice me how to get this working?

Below is my `saveTokenToDatabase` method which am using to save notification.

```
public void saveTokenToDatabase(String title, String message, String image) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference notificationDatabase = database.getReference("user_notifications");
    String key = notificationDatabase.push().getKey();
    String userSessionId = "peter123";
    if(userSessionId.equals("NULL")){
        return;
    }
    //Create Object saveNotifications
    saveNotifications newmessages = new saveNotifications(message, title, "firebase", image, userSessionId, key);
    notificationDatabase.child(userSessionId).child(key).setValue(newmessages).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(_this, "Token Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(_this, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Below is the a `send` method which I call in Firebase `onMessageReceived` method for `RemoteMessage`

```
 void send(int type, String title, String message, Bitmap image, String imageurl, String clickAction) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) _this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && notificationManager != null){
            createChannel(notificationManager);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(_this, MainActivity.class);

        switch(type){
            case 1:
                title = _this.getString(R.string.loc_fail);
                message = _this.getString(R.string.loc_fail_text);
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                break;

            case 2:
                title = _this.getString(R.string.app_name);
                message = _this.getString(R.string.loc_perm_text);
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                break;

            case 3:
            default:
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                //intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                break;
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("NotificationClickAction", clickAction);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(_this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + _this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification_alert);
        Vibrator vibration = (Vibrator) _this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_this, Utils.CHANNEL_ID);

        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        notificationBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(_this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{350, 700, 350, 700, 350});
        notificationBuilder.setWhen(when);
        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(false);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setTicker(_this.getString(R.string.app_name));
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        if(image != null){
            notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(image);
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(image));/*Notification with Image*/
        }else{
            notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_this.getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(_this.getString(R.string.loc_perm_more)));
        }
        if(vibration != null) { vibration.vibrate(1000); }
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
            saveTokenToDatabase(title, message, imageurl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are u using cloud functions?

Comment: @PeterHaddad please can you explain to me what you mean by if am using cloud functions.

Comment: From where are you sending notifications to the user? You either need to use a server or cloud functions https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions